# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting ')'

Tags: php, magento, syntax

Iam trying to install magento and upload all the files to my server. now when i got to the root/setup i get this

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting ')' setup/index.php on line 29

Here is the php file

```
<?php
/**
* Copyright © 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
* See COPYING.txt for license details.
*/

if (PHP_SAPI == 'cli') {
echo "You cannot run this from the command line." . PHP_EOL .
    "Run \"php bin/magento\" instead." . PHP_EOL;
exit(1);
}
try {
require __DIR__ . '/../app/bootstrap.php';
} catch (\Exception $e) {
echo <<<HTML
<div style="font:12px/1.35em arial, helvetica, sans-serif;">
<div style="margin:0 0 25px 0; border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;">
    <h3 style="margin:0;font-size:1.7em;font-weight:normal;text-transform:none;text-align:left;color:#2f2f2f;">
    Autoload error</h3>
</div>
<p>{$e->getMessage()}</p>
</div>
HTML;
exit(1);
}

// For Setup Wizard we are using our customized error handler
$handler = new \Magento\Framework\App\ErrorHandler();
set_error_handler([$handler, 'handler']);

\Zend\Mvc\Application::init(require __DIR__ . '/config/application.config.php')->run();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Line 29 is:

> ```
> set_error_handler([$handler, 'handler']);
> ```

This code requires PHP >= 5.4, and you're using 5.3 or older. You'll need to upgrade your version of PHP, or use an older version of Magento that does not require PHP 5.4.

Magento 1.x is [documented to require PHP 5.4 or newer](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/system-requirements.html). [2.x requires 5.5 or newer](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/system-requirements.html).